# How create single create action for multiple models with TPH approach

Tags: asp.net-mvc, view, binding

I have base class Contract

```
public abstract class Contract
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int ContractID { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    [Required]
    public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    [Required]
    public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }
}
```

And two other classes derive from this class: CreditContract and PrepaymentContract.

```
public class CreditContract : Contract
{
    [Required]
    public float CreditLimit { get; set; }

    [Column(TypeName = "char")]
    [StringLength(3)]
    [Required]
    public string CreditLimitCurrency { get; set; }
}

public class PrepaymentContract : Contract
{
    [Required]
    public float PrepaymentAmount { get; set; }

    [Column(TypeName = "char")]
    [StringLength(1)]
    [Required]
    public string PrepaymentPeriod { get; set; }
}
```

Additionally I've created ContractViewModel class.

```
public int SelectedContract { get; set; }
public CreditContract creditContract { get; set; }
public PrepaymentContract prepaymentContract { get; set; }
```

My Create method looks like this:

```
public ActionResult Create(ContractViewModel contract)
    {
        if (contract.SelectedCategory == 1)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                contract.creditContract.StartDate = contract.StartDate;
                contract.creditContract.EndDate = contract.EndDate;
                db.Contracts.Add(contract.creditContract);
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            return View(contract.creditContract);
        }
        else
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                contract.prepaymentContract.StartDate = contract.StartDate;
                contract.prepaymentContract.EndDate = contract.EndDate;
                db.Contracts.Add(contract.prepaymentContract);
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            return View(contract.prepaymentContract);
        }
    }
```

And my Create view looks like this:

```
@model CodeFirstInheritance.ViewModels.ContractViewModel
    <div class="form-horizontal">
    <h4>Course</h4>
    <hr />
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.creditContract.StartDate, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.creditContract.StartDate, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.creditContract.StartDate, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.creditContract.EndDate, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.creditContract.EndDate, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.creditContract.EndDate, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.SelectedCategory, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.SelectedCategory, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.SelectedCategory, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.creditContract.CreditLimit, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.creditContract.CreditLimit, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.creditContract.CreditLimit, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.creditContract.CreditLimitCurrency, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.creditContract.CreditLimitCurrency, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.creditContract.CreditLimitCurrency, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Can I do something like that:

E.g:

```
var selectedContract = contract.SelectedCategory.Enum; 
if (ModelState.IsValid) 
{ 
    selectedContractt.StartDate = contract.StartDate; 
    selectedContract.EndDate = contract.EndDate; 
    db.Contracts.Add(contract.creditContract); 
    db.SaveChanges(); 

    return RedirectToAction("Index"); 
}
```

return View(selectedContract);

Comment: CreditContract and PrepaymentContract classes derive from Contract class. And only has 1~2 fields different. So in my view in form controls I've clearly specified all inputs for creditContract model. And I think I went wrong, because I will need duplicate this for PrepaymentContract model too (eg. model.PrepaymentContract.StartDate).

Comment: Can I do something like, In my contract class I have two columns: start and end date, in creditContract I only have limitCredit column. I want in my view do something like this: put credit.startDate, credit.endDate and creditContract.limitCredit into creditContract model. How can I do this? Because I want to do simulart to prepaymentContract, but prepaymentContract.someField.

Comment: Hi I've updated my post below.